# Databricks to SQL connection Error : [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server'

Tags: python, sql-server, odbc, azure-databricks, databricks-sql

I am trying to connect to Azure SQL from Databricks by using following

```
import pyodbc

# Connect to Azure SQL database
server = 'xxxx.database.windows.net'
database = 'db-dev-xxxx'
username = 'abc'
password = 'xyz'
driver= '{ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}'

cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER='+driver+';SERVER='+server+';PORT=1433;DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD='+ password)
```

However, I get the following error

#### Error

```
Error: ('01000', "[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server': file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)")
Command took 0.19 seconds -- by g@xxx.onmicrosoft.com at 3/1/2023, 3:59:15 PM on g @xxx.onmicrosoft.com's Cluster
```

Any suggestions/advice would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why not just use `spark.read.format("jdbc")...` ? You don't need to install anything as drivers are already installed. See details here: https://docs.databricks.com/external-data/jdbc.html

Answer (score 2):

> **('01000', "[0100] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL'**

The above error mainly happens because of the drivers properly not installed.

**I tried to reproduce the same in my environment I got same error.**

[image]

**To resolve the above error. Please follow this approach:**

Run the following command to install ODBC drivers on the Databricks cluster.

```
%sh
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add -
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/16.04/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get -q -y install msodbcsql17
```

[image]

Now, you can check the Azure Databricks connected to SQL server.

> **Code:**

```
import pyodbc
server = 'vamsisyn.database.windows.net'
database = 'database_name'
username = 'xxxx'
password = 'xxxx'
    
conn1 = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER=' + server + ';DATABASE='+ database +';UID=' + username + ';PWD='+ password)
```

[image]